# Concat,Concatenate,TextJoin, all return '#NAME?'

Tags: excel, openpyxl

so I have this simple code that should insert a formula into a cell:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet('General')
ws['A1'].value = 'Hello'
ws['B1'].value = 'World'
#Now cell C1 should display 'Hello World'
ws['C1'].value = "=CONCAT(A1,B1)"
#ws['C1'].value = "=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)"
#ws['C1'].value = "=TEXTJOIN(,,A1,B1)"
wb.save('Test.xlsx')
```

I've manually entered entered the formula in Excel and they work, but when assigned via openpyxl they return #NAME?

[image]

The formula in cell C1 checks out, if I select the cell and hit enter or double click it and then click outside, it shows the correct result; 
I've also tried with but still no luck:

```
ws['C1'].set_explicit_value("=CONCAT(A1,B1)","f")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the OOXML specification only covers the formulae that were in the original release and not those that Microsoft has added in subsequent releases.

You can easily check whether a formula is ok:

```
from openpyxl.utils.formulas import FORMULAE
'CONCAT' in FORMULAE
False
'CONCATENATE' in FORMULAE
True
'TEXTJOIN' in FORMULAE
False
```

In order to use more recent formulae, these must be prefixed with `'_xlfn.'`. If there are still problems then you will need to look at the XML source of the relevant files.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using 'CONCATENATE'.

Answer (score 0):

`.Value` property explicitly sets the Range's well... value

**If you intend on using formula, you should use the `.Formula` property instead:**

```
ws['C1'].Formula = "=CONCAT(A1,B1)"
```

should yield the expected result. Feel like it's pretty self-explanatory as to why.

---

**EDIT:**

Note, this will produce the expected result "`HelloWorld`", however it appears you desired the result to be  "`Hello World`" instead.

To achieve the above mentioned result, use this formula instead:

```
ws['C1'].Formula = "=CONCAT(A1, " ", B1)
```

*Last but not least as @tigeravatar correctly mentioned in the comments, in older Excel version use the formula `=CONCATENATE()`instead!*

Comment: Note that the CONCAT function will only work if you are on Excel 2016 or Office 365 or higher.  It didn't exist prior to then.  If you're on an earlier version of Excel, you'll need to use the full CONCATENATE version

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ws['C1'].Formula = "=CONCAT(A1,B1)"
AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'Formula'`

Comment: This answer does not apply to the openpyxl library. It looks like it refers to the VBA interface for Excel files.